# Refreshing GAC references without restarting C# application

Tags: c#

I have a C# application that checks for a missing dll. If it is missing, then it runs an installer which installs the dll into the GAC. However, once it is installed, I find that the program still can't find the dll (I just run the class that references it and see if there is a FileNotFoundException.) Is there a way of refreshing the GAC references from the perspective of the running app?

Comment: This is by design, the CLR remembers fails assembly loads and will consistently fail them later.  A DLL Hell counter-measure.  A little shell program that does this, then starts your app would be a simple workaround.  Not otherwise very different from an installer.

Comment: Is this failed information stored in the CurrentDomain?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of waiting for a failure, why not check for the DLL on application startup, and install if necessary *before you try to call any methods from the assembly*?

Alternatively, keep your current implementation, but after you've installed the DLL, reload the assembly explicitly using `Assembly.Load(...)`

Comment: I'm trying something similar to that. Currently if it fails once, Assembly.Load seems to fail for that AppDomain.

Comment: ... I can't say I'm surprised, but how about my first suggestion? If you don't try to access anything from the assembly before your installation check, the assembly shouldn't be marked as failed.